# How to create a submit button and link to open in new page rather than printing result on page?

Tags: php, database, random, mysqli, web

I am using this code to query my database which has 10 links. Currently this code prints the link out on the top of my page (the page which queries this). I want a "lucky dip" button to feature on this page, and then when you click the button it should open a random link inside of my database, rather than appearing in text format at the top of my page.

Thanks for any help in advance

```
}else{
        //query db here
        $row = clean_string($db_server, $_POST["ROWname"]) ;
        //create sqli query
        $query = "SELECT link FROM landmark ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
        //query db
        mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
        $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
        if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));

        //print out any rows
        $message = "";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $str_result .= $row['link'] . " "; 
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        echo $message . $str_result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that you should be doing this kind of thing (people usually don't like being redirected like that), but who am I to judge?

It looks like you want to do two things:

1. Set `<form target="_blank"` on the html form you're using.
2. In your php, instead of echoing the url, do `header("Location: ' . $message . $str_result);`